# Kotlin: How do I save the contents of an ImageView to the internal/external memory?

Tags: android, kotlin

So... I got this easy project where when clicking a button uses an intent to open the camera, take a picture, and if the user presses "OK" will display the photo image inside an ImageView, this is a fragment...

On a button I call the camera intent and got the result URI in the `image_uri` variable, so I put this image in the ImageView object with:

```
imageView.setImageURI(image_uri)
```

Now, I want to save this image into the internal/external memory, or gallery. I saw many answers, and many tutorials on line to make this that says you have to use `buildDrawingCache()` method, problem is, Android Studio says this method is deprecated in Java.

So what do I have to do?

PS: I'm pretty new to Kotlin/Android development, so I don't know which parameters do I have to give you. I'm using **Android Studio 3.4.1**, **JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01** using **Windows 10**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an image from camera intent, you can get it as Bitmap and save to your storage.

```
class MainActity : AppCompatActivity() { 
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
        //Get img from camera intent
        val img: Bitmap? = intent?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap?
        img?.let { img ->
             val root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath
             val imgFile = = File(root, "myImg.jpg")
             img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, FileOutputStream(imgFile))

             //Alert gallery to update images
             val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE).apply {
                 data = Uri.fromFile(imgFile)
             }
             this@MainActivity.sendBroadcast(intent)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for, how to convert the image to bitmap to file